# Webdav: Enumerating directory items

Tags: php, webdav

I am implementing a webdav server in PHP for Apache. I would like to know which of the webdav methods (e.g., GET, PUT, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, etc.) do webdav clients usually use to enumerate or list the contents (files) in a folder? the relevant RFCs are somewhat unclear about this.

Furthermore, what sort of response is expected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant RFC is RFC 4918. The [description of PROPFIND](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#rfc.section.9.1) starts with:

"The PROPFIND method retrieves properties defined on the resource identified by the Request-URI, if the resource does not have any internal members, or on the resource identified by the Request-URI and potentially its member resources, if the resource is a collection that has internal member URLs...."

Isn't that sufficiently clear?