# PROPFIND Request In WTClient

Tags: objective-c, ios, webdav, file-sharing, cfnetwork

I would like to add a WebDAV and iDisk interface to my app, however I am having a bit of technical trouble regarding files stored on the server.  Every answer to the question "[How do I use a WebDAV server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883075/webdav-client-library-for-ios) || [to get a list of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065476/webdav-enumerating-directory-items)" seems to end with the phrase "Use a PROPFIND request."  I've decided to use the WTClient Classes because they establish and terminate the stream to the server for me and manage uploads and downloads, but here's where WTClient fails: It cannot gather a list of files on the server (or I seem to be unable to gather a list, whatever floats your boat).  It puts in the PROPFIND request with this line:

```
WTHTTPConnection *connection = [[WTHTTPConnection alloc] initWithDestination:remoteURL
                                    protocol:@"PROPFIND"];
```

It then gathers the results as an `NSDictionary`.  But instead of using that dictionary to get a list of files, WTClient uses it to gather error code information (if present) from the XML in the dictionary.  While helpful, it is not what I'm looking for.  If anyone has even the foggiest idea of how to request the files on a WebDAV server and gather them into an `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from [source of WTClient](http://code.google.com/p/wtclient/source/browse/trunk/WTClient/WTClient.m) you need to use `initWithLocalURL`, `preparePropertiesConnection` and/or `requestProperties` to achieve what you want.

OTOH it seems from some comments in the source that esp. the functionality around `PROPFIND` (which is indeed necessary to get a directory listing from WebDAV) is not fully implemented yet... so it might be that this would not work for your use case.

**UPDATE**:

[This](https://github.com/ccgus/flycode/tree/master/WebDAV) is a WebDAV-client library including source which has been successfully used on iOS (with very little modification). It include an implementation for `PROPFIND` and other WebDAV-specific http verbs... to me it seems that this would be nice starting point for you.

Comment: Does ASIHTTPRequest have PROPFIND fully implemented then?

Comment: @CodaFi `ASIHTTPRequest` is a nice implementation of HTTP but it does not know anything about WebDAV/PROPFIND... perhaps you can use it to write your own implementation of a WebDAV client...

Comment: Perhaps, but I've been googling around and there seem to be quite a few success stories of people uploading and downloading files to WebDAV and iDisk servers with ASI, and I was going for more of a pages-esque implementation, as in a list.

Comment: @CodaFi upload (=HTTP PUT) and download (=HTTP GET) are basic HTTP verbs which are supported by ASI and others. But your question was about PROPFIND which is a WebDAV-specific HTTP verb! please see my update about a nice WebDAV-client library...

Comment: Oh! This is written in Cocoa... well, I guess I have a night of translation ahead of me.

Comment: I know this is getting long, and I appreciate your help with this.  For suggesting the FlyCode implementation (which I had previously overlooked), I may as well award you the bounty.